# Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer/SimpleMessageListenerContainer (JMS/AMQP) Annotation configuration

Tags: spring-annotations, spring-jms

So I'm working on a project where many teams are using common services and following a common architecture. One of the services in use is messaging, currently JMS with ActiveMQ. Pretty much all teams are required to follow a strict set of rules for creating and sending messages, namely, everything is pub-subscribe and the messages that are sent are somewhat like the following:

```
public class WorkDTO {

   private String type;
   private String subtype;
   private String category;
   private String jsonPayload; // converted custom Java object

}
```

The 'jsonPayload' comes from a base class that all teams extend from so it has common attributes.

So basically in JMS, everyone is always sending the same kind of message, but to different ActiveMQ Topics. When the message (WorkDTO) is sent via JMS, first it is converted into a JSON object then it is sent in a TextMessage.

Whenever a team wishes to create a subscriber for a topic, they create a DefaultMessageListenerContainer and configure it appropriately to receive messages (We are using Java-based Spring configuration). Basically every DefaultMessageListenerContainer that a team defines is pretty much the same except for maybe the destination from which to receive messages and the message handler.

I was wondering how anyone would approach further abstracting the messaging configuration via annotations in such a case? Meaning, since everyone is pretty much required to follow the same requirements, could something like the following be useful:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Listener {

     String destination();

     boolean durable() default false;

     long receiveTimeout() default -1; // -1 use JMS default

     String defaultListenerMethod() default "handleMessage";


     // more config details here

}


@Listener(destination="PX.Foo", durable=true)
public class FooListener {

     private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // converts JSON Strings to Java Classes

     public void handleMessage(TextMessage message){

         String text = message.getText();
         WorkDTO dto = mapper.readValue(text, WorkDto.class);

         String payload = dto.getPayload();
         String type = dto.getType();
         String subType = dto.getSubType();
         String category = dto.getCategory();
     }
}
```

Of course I left out the part on how to configure the DefaultMessageListenerContainer by use of the @Listener annotation. I started looking into a BeanFactoryPostProcessor to create the necessary classes and add them to the application context, but I don't know how to do all that.

The reason I ask the question is that we are switching to AMQP/RabbitMQ from JMS/ActiveMQ and would like to abstract the messaging configuration even further by use of annotations. I know AMQP is not like JMS so the configuration details would be slightly different. I don't believe we will be switching from AMQP to something else.

Here teams only need to know the name of the destination and whether they want to make their subscription durable.

This is just something that popped into my head just recently. Any thoughts on this?

I don't want to do something overly complicated though so the other alternative is to create a convenience method that returns a pre-configured DefaultMessageListenerContainer given a destination and a message handler:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig{

    @Autowired
    private MessageConfigFactory configFactory;

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer fooListenerContainer(){

         return configFactory.getListenerContainer("PX.Foo", new FooListener(), true);
    }
}

class MessageConfigFactory {

    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer getListener(String destination, Object listener, boolean durable) {

      DefaultMessageListenerContainer l = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
      // configuration details here

      return l;

    }
}
```